# JavaScript for Auto Login

Tags: javascript

I have a website that I want to create a script for. I just want to be able to, whenever opening the script, the username and password fields are filled in, and it automatically logins for you. This is what the code looks like for the username and password on the website:

```
<input onkeydown="javascript:submitForm(event);" name="username" type="text" size="20">

<input onkeydown="javascript:submitForm(event);" name="password" type="password" size="18">
```

This is the form action by the way, I don't know if it's needed:

```
<form action="https://secure.usli.com/CustomerLogin/login.ashx" method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
```

Comment: Is there any good reason why you don't use their provided logging method? This is a really bad idea because you will need to store password on your web browser or your script.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a service such as lastpass for this. 
They have an autologin feature which seems to do exactly what you want.

https://forums.lastpass.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2949#p11389